# Why this custom editor is not working : Tour Builder WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

To understand my issue See this [Click HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGcnI.png)

Here is the Steps Setting Code :

```
<div class="group-inside">

            <?php $mb->the_field('steptitle'); ?>
            <p><label>Step Title</label></p>
            <p><input type="text" size="60" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

            <p class="warning update-warning"><?php _e( 'Sort order has been changed.  Remember to save the post to save these changes.' );?></p>
            <?php
            // 'html' is used for the "Text" editor tab.
            if ( 'html' === wp_default_editor() ) {
                add_filter( 'the_editor_content', 'wp_htmledit_pre' );
                $switch_class = 'html-active';
            } else {
                add_filter( 'the_editor_content', 'wp_richedit_pre' );
                $switch_class = 'tmce-active';
            }
            ?>
            <?php $mb->the_field('textarea'); ?>
            <p><label>Step Description</label></p>
            <div class="customEditor wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap <?php echo 'tmce-active'; //echo $switch_class;?>">          
                <div class="wp-editor-tools hide-if-no-js">
                    <div class="wp-media-buttons custom_upload_buttons">
                        <?php do_action( 'media_buttons' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wp-editor-tabs">
                        <a data-mode="html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html"> <?php _ex( 'Text', 'Name for the Text editor tab (formerly HTML)' ); ?></a>
                        <a data-mode="tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce"><?php _e('Visual'); ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- .wp-editor-tools -->
                <div class="wp-editor-container">
                      <textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="10" cols="50" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" rows="3"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_editor_content', html_entity_decode( $mb->get_the_value() ) ) ); ?></textarea>
                </div>
                // Here is the problem
                <p><span><?php _e('Enter in some text');?></span></p>
            </div> <!-- .end-editor-tools -->

            <?php $selectedst = ' selected="selected"'; ?>
            <?php $mb->the_field('steptype'); ?>
            <p><label>Step Type</label></p>
            <p><select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="modal"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'modal') echo $selectedst; ?>>Modal</option>
            <option value="tooltip"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'tooltip') echo $selectedst; ?>>Tooltip</option>
            <option value="nohighlight"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'nohighlight') echo $selectedst; ?>>No Highlight</option>
            </select></p>

            <?php $selectedwt = ' selected="selected"'; ?>
            <?php $mb->the_field('wraptype'); ?>
            <p><label>Wrapper Type</label><p>
            <select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="id"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'id') echo $selectedwt; ?>>ID</option>
            <option value="class"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'class') echo $selectedwt; ?>>Class</option>
            <option value="name"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'name') echo $selectedwt; ?>>Name</option>
            </select></p>

            <?php $mb->the_field('wrapname'); ?> 
            <p> <label>Wrapper Selector </label></p>
            <span>for class insert the point. Eg. ".entry-title"</span>
            <p><input type="text" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/>
            </p>

            <?php $mb->the_field('stepwidth'); ?> 
            <p> <label>Width </label></p>
            <p> <input type="text" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/>
            </p>


            <?php $selectedpos = ' selected="selected"'; ?>
            <?php $mb->the_field('steppos'); ?>
            <p><label>Position</label></p> 
            <p> <select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="top"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'top') echo $selectedpos; ?>>Top</option>
            <option value="bottom"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'bottom') echo $selectedpos; ?>>Bottom</option>
            <option value="right"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'right') echo $selectedpos; ?>>Right</option>
            <option value="left"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'left') echo $selectedpos; ?>>Left</option>
            </select></p>

            <?php $selectedwd = ' selected="selected"'; ?>
            <?php $mb->the_field('wrapdrag'); ?>
            <p><label>Draggable</label><p>
            <select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="no"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'no') echo $selectedwd; ?>>No</option>
            <option value="yes"<?php if ($mb->get_the_value() == 'yes') echo $selectedwd; ?>>Yes</option>
            </select></p>

            <?php $mb->the_field('steprotation'); ?>
            <p><label>Rotation (degrees)</label></p>
            <p><input type="text" size="60" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

            <?php $mb->the_field('stepredirect'); ?>
            <p><label>Redirect Url</label></p>
            <span>Always insert prefix http://</span>
            <p><input type="text" size="60" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p>

          <?php /*?>  <?php $mb->the_field('steptime'); ?>
            <p><label>Time</label></p>
            <p><input type="text" size="60" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>" value="<?php $mb->the_value(); ?>"/></p><?php */?>

        </div><!-- .group-inside -->
    </div><!-- .group-wrap -->
```

When i am pressing **text** button or **Visual** button below **Step Description** , there is no change, screen remains same or this text area is hidden, So with this i am not able to type my text. How to make this text area in working so I can type in this text area?

**Image  describe it more clearly:**
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the screen shot of what the actual issue you facing?

Comment: To understand my issue See this Click HERE   click on Click Here in this line on very top

Comment: it is custom post type?

Comment: @Harshita, 
Is there any js error on your console?
And is this a plugin or the custom post type?

Comment: No there is not any type of error in console

Comment: Is this a plug-in or custom post type?